# Android 2.3.3 Applications List menu code example?

Tags: android, list, menu, scrollable, animated

just wondering where I could find code example about the menu list with all the applications in your android phone as image icons. You can scroll down in apps icons and there is the speed as ur finger goes. Also, multiples sections divide the icons into sections : like the section download.

Comment: it'd be beneficial if you could attach a picture, to understand which menus you require

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Android Git mirrors on Github: [the source code for the part of the Settings app that manages applications might be what you're looking for](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java).

Answer (score 0):

There is one example available as a part of the **apidemos** samples in android-sdk. If you have installed APIDemos in your phone or emulator then you can browse to **App->Loader->Custom**. It should look like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The application list in 2.3.3 looks like this where is the code of that?

[Here](http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/4e0cb6e0cadcbbc53f020000-590/the-galaxy-s-ii-runs-android-version-233-not-a-huge-fan-of-the-touchwiz-skin-though.jpg)